# Horizontal Margins and Block formatting context

Tags: css

Why the horizontal space between `column2` and `column3` are only `5%` not `10% = 5% + 5%`?

The horizonal margin between  `column1` and `column2` is as expected `10%`.

`column3`is a BFC. Is this the reason why `column2` and `column3` magins collapse?

I am not trying to do a layout. I am just curious how and why it happened.

**The Left margin of `column 3` is gone because of `float:none` property. Why?**

```css
.column {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5%;
  text-align:center;
}

/* Establishing a new block formatting 
   context in the last column */
.bfc {
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden; 
  margin-left:20%; /*This property added later.Where does this margin go?*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">column 1</div>
  <div class="column">column 2</div>
  <div class="column bfc">column 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by `float: none;` in class `.bfc`, to solve it, just comment it out, example:

```
.bfc {
    /*float: none;*/
}
```

The reason you have a visual difference in `margin`is that Floated elements remain a part of the flow of the web page, when you remove the `float` property using `none` (as you did for your last column), it gets `static` for it positioning instead.

```css
    .column {
      width: 20%;
      background-color: green;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 5%;
      text-align:center;
    }

    /* Establishing a new block formatting 
       context in the last column */
    .bfc {
      /*float: none;*/
      overflow: hidden; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column">column 1</div>
      <div class="column">column 2</div>
      <div class="column bfc">column 3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `when you remove the float property using none (as you did for your last column), it gets static for it positioning instead.`? What does this mean? you mean `position:static`?

Comment: @J.Joe thanks for commenting, I hope I can give you more information below: when you remove float for an element, the element return to its original flow (position). Every elements in HTML have position:static has default (even if you do not add this property on your css). With static, Elements render in order, as they appear in the document flow. I hope this explanation helps you. Please let me know.

Comment: But `column 3` also has a left and right margins. Even it is rendered in order, its margins should exist. With `float:none`, its left margin is gone.

Comment: Using float:none The element is not floated, and will be displayed just where it occurs in the text with its position as default static.

Comment: But where is the left margin of `column 3` if use `float:none`? If you use Chrome Web Develop Tools, you will see the left margin of `column 3` is underneath the right margin of `column 2`. How can that happen?

Comment: This happens because the element with float:none goes out of the the flow creating by the element with applied  float:left, you can read the specification here https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html

Comment: If you found an useful answer on your question, please  do not forget to up-vote of accept an answer :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.column {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 5%;
  text-align:center;
}

/* Establishing a new block formatting 
   context in the last column */
.bfc {
  
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">column 1</div>
  <div class="column">column 2</div>
  <div class="column bfc">column 3</div>
</div>
```

you should use "display: inline-block" instead of float left.Then it will work fine. The Problem was the float:none property of bfc. It will take the left margin from the end of previous element.

Comment: `It will take the left margin from the end of previous element.`? Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

You just remove the class .bfc from your css. Actually its not necessary. It causes the style problem.